# "Subclass" Core Data Model

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, core-data

I have a project which uses Core Data and has two targets. These targets have several shared entities. For this moment I'm maintaining two separate models with duplicated entities, which, in my opinion, is not efficient.

Is there are any way to have shared data model as parent for data model in concrete target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you can create "nested Core Data models" (but perhaps someone else does).

What you could do is to create a model containing all entities, and two [Configurations](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdMOM.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002328-SW3), one for each target.

A configuration contains the union of all entities used in a persistent store, and you can specify a configuration when you create or add the persistent store with

```
addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:
```